# Error in published paper not present in the free copies for author

Tags: publications

A few months ago a published a paper in a highly reputed journal. There were last-minute corrections. Finally, I received a link to share the article. The version obtained through the link was ok and I own a PDF copy of it. The link does not work anymore.

Now I see that the current online version of the manuscript on the website does not include those corrections.

I desire that the error be fixed. I wish to know what can be done to solve the problem.

Clearly, I plan to write to the Journal for this issue. But I do not know in detail the scientific publication system, so I do not know what to expect or exactly what to ask for. What should I do?

---

Additional info:

If it matters, the mistake does not change any aspect of the science of the paper. It is related to the description of an equation and the mistake (and the correct description) should be obvious for the readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For online publication, just contact the editor and let them know of the problem, including that you were sent a correct version. It is probably easy to fix as long as they know of the problem, but they might not if you don't tell them.

Emphasize that these aren't *new* changes you request, but just that they seem to have put up the wrong version.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I was thinking to contact directly to the editorial manager because the issue is more closely related to administrative proceeses than to science itself. Does it make sense?

Comment: Actually anyone from the editor on up for whom you have contact. But someone you have corresponded with previously might be best. That way the context is clear to the organization.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a minor administrative hiccup from the publisher's side where they had two versions of the manuscript and uploaded the older one by mistake.

I would point this out to the production staff (the people who sent you the proofs) and expect that they'll be able to handle it. Notifying the editorial board is likely not necessary, since it's got nothing to do with peer review.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.